# linking foreign Key of unknown table in a relational database

Tags: sql, database, orm, foreign-keys, h2

I am currently trying to set up a relational database (H2) that projects an object orientated structure of JAVA Model into the relational tables of my database. I am using the JDBC and H2 RDBMS.

So Here is my problem: 
I have an object of type "attribute" that is supposed to be stored in the table "attribute". The owner of this attribute can either be an object of type "Function" or of type "Block" who both have a table on their own. One attribute-object can only be owned by one object (either function or block), making this a 1:n cardinality.

I am however struggling with how to include the owner in the attribute table. If I create a table named "ownerID" and store the ID of the owner (a globally unique ID btw) in it, the Database is missing the information about which table is containing this ID (even though its a GUID).

-Is it okay for example, to include another column containing the name of the table that the owner_ID belongs to ?

-another idea was to include one "functionOwnerID" column and one "blockOwnerID" and leaving one of them empty, but this seems like a rather dirty solution to me.

I hope my description of the problem was clear, and thanks in advance !

best regards, 
Moritz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Is it okay for example, to include another column containing the name of the table that the owner_ID belongs to ?"

That's how polymorphic relationships work! :)

Edit: (yes, you can do that and it's actually pretty common)

---

References:

- (Rails/ActiveRecord Docs): http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations
- (Laravel/Eloquent Docs): https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations